# How to align text in a span

Tags: html, css

There are two spans side by side. The first one holds a caret and the other one has text.
I am trying to acheive the text alignment as in pic1, but what i get is pic2.
This can be acheived by using a table instead of ul li i know, but is there any other way by css

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <span><b class="right-caret"></b></span>
  <span>
   Click <a href="#">here</a> to know how to provide the feedback.
  </span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span><b class="right-caret"></b></span>
  <span>
    Unable to Login or use the feedback form?
    Please report it <a href="#">here</a>.
  </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pic 1:

[image]

Pic 2:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/hc6kajv2/

Comment: yes and pic 1 is what normally happens with `li` elements, can you post your css? There must be something in there that is causing this to behave differently

Comment: You can use this syntax ul {
    list-style-image: url('rightcaret.gif');
 } to customize the li tag instead of using the b tag and span

Comment: why does it have to be a `span`? a `div` instead a `span` in the element that wraps the text will do exactly what you want - http://jsbin.com/nenona/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @jmore009 in your website whalor.com what is the name of the js framework to do the text print/delete animation plz ?

Comment: @ZeRuBuES its called [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (maybe not elegant) solution is to set the `li`s to `position: relative` and the arrow to `position: absolute`:

```
.right-caret {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hc6kajv2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of `span` [With bullet](http://jsfiddle.net/hc6kajv2/1/) ,  [Without bullet](http://jsfiddle.net/hc6kajv2/2/)

```
li:before { 
content: "";
border-color: transparent red;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
display: block;
height: 0;
width: 0;
left: -1em;
top: 0.9em;
position: relative;
}
```

## EDIT

You have a `margin-left` clear it

http://jsfiddle.net/hc6kajv2/2/

Comment: Thank you. But still not the desired output. The second text line in the li should start from the same position as the first.